# Disable select boxes with CakePHP InputDefaults (FormHelper)

Tags: cakephp, select, input, formhelper

I am having dificulties creating some form defaults with the FormHelper of CakePHP2.

I have some input fields which I want to be readonly, and some select boxes to be disabled.

I have the following code this far:

```
echo $this->Form->create(
    'User',
    array(
        'novalidate' => true,
        'inputDefaults' => array(
            'div' => false,
            'placeholder' => '...',
            'readonly' => 'readonly'
        )
    )
);
```

This code is setting my select boxes to readonly. How can I target input and select boxes individually?

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to put readonly in options array, like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Field', array ("label" => '', 'id'=> '', 'readonly'=>'readonly'));
```

The same with disabled:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Field', array ("label" => '', 'id'=> '', 'disabled'=>'disabled'));
```

That's it ;D

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to realize this in form defaults so I didn't have to code this with every input/select field.

Comment: But, if you do this in the form create, they will be valid for all the inputs of that form. If you want some creteria in this disable, i think you have to do `if`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I just want all select boxes to be disabled and input fields to be readonly. Setting this through jquery is unfortunately not an option...